# How to Organise large winforms class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form class that has a tab control with many tabs.  The problem is as the visual user interface is growing ever larger due to the number of tabs, the code that handles all the controls event is also becoming very large.

I am looking for the best technique in how you would organise this.

Currently I have split much of the code into separate:

```
#region
#endregion
```

To help organise it.  I also had the idea of possibly using form inheritance but I dont think this will solve my problem exactly.  The other idea I had was to separate the events of each tab into partial classes.

Is there an easier or more practical way that I am missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Are the tabs independent? Could spawn off seperate files for each tab as User Controls. Don't have to be truly independent, but would simplify things for you if they were. Otherwise, some work to be done to do so.

Comment: Its one tab control with about 10 tabs, each with an ever growing number of controls.

Comment: I meant that for each tab, do the controls and data interact only with each other? If so, it would be easy to make each tab into a user control. If not, still doable for sure just takes some work to link everything back together.

Comment: What I'd do, is separate each of the tabs controls, into specific user controls, which will allow you to have the user controls maintain their own methods etc. 

It's quite possibly going to be quite a lot of work, but in the long run, you'll find it easier to maintain.

Also, while building the user controls, why not see if there is any commonality between functions and merge, within a new user control?

Comment: Ah OK see what you mean, well some of the controls across the multiple tabs share the same methods

Comment: Then it's an ideal opportunity to make use of User controls. You'll find you'll be able to thin out the code a fair bit, especially if you're reusing bits here and there.

Comment: looks like you need some pattern/design. In fact the design of an application depends on how long the application will be developed and how large it can grow. When it can become large and complicated, we need a corresponding design, it's not easy, coding well is not enough if the design is bad. Even bad design makes you won't be able to code anymore at some level of development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do, is separate each of the tabs controls, into specific user controls, which will allow you to have the user controls maintain their own methods etc. It's quite possibly going to be quite a lot of work, but in the long run, you'll find it easier to maintain. Also, while building the user controls, why not see if there is any commonality between functions and merge, within a new user control?